# backbone body view not rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a stupid mistake somewhere and I cannot make a base backbone view get rendered. Can someone please point me what's wrong in this code?

```
var view = new Backbone.View({
    el: 'body',
    template: '<p>this is my new template</p>',
    render: function() {
        console.log('rendering myself');
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }
});

view.render();
```

PS the console.log is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're syntax is a bit off, you should be first defining your view and then instantiating it.

```
//define view 
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    template: '<p>this is my new template</p>',
    render: function() {
        console.log('rendering myself');
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }
});

//create view instance
var view = new MyView();
view.render();
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uducev/1/edit)

Comment: first of all, there should be `view.render();` instead of `myView.render();` - but that's a tiny problem. A bigger problem is that the view isn't rendered (<p>this is my new template</p> is not attached to DOM)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Check now it should be rendered, I also added a jsbin.

Comment: thanks. But still I can't get it rendered in my browser. I can see that the view.el is undefined, dunno why. In JsBin everythng works fine.

Comment: If it's not rendering by you than make sure that you instantiate and render the view after the `DOM` is loaded, I think that in the jsBin (and jsFiddle) by default it loads the JavaScript in the `ready` event.

Comment: Damn, man, you're good :) thanks. In fact, my view was created before the page rendering was finished. The view I had created was pointing to no existing DOM node.

Answer (score 2):

While the conventional way is to extend Backbone.view, and instantiate new instances of a view (per Jack's answer), you can get what you want (instantiating a simple view) by wrapping Backbone.View.extend in parens:

```
var view = new (Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    template: '<p>this is my new template</p>',
    render: function() {
        console.log('rendering myself');
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }
}));

view.render();
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axorih/1/edit)

This can be helpful for "one off" views/routers/etc, that you don't intend reinstantiating multiple times. The method in Jack's answer is more readable (and useful) for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually create that view.

Before render: function(){}

Add

```
initialize: function(){
    this.render();
}
```

and when you want to load the page / view use this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
     new view({"el:body});
});
```

Although normally a view variable should be extended from Backbone view.

So instead of "var view" ... it should be something like
window.myView = Backbone.View.extend( { } )

See http://backbonejs.org/#View

It's easier to manage when the views represent objects.